# Remove noise and detect semicircle opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

Are there ways to detect semicircle on these images?

Tried many ways and all give bad results

Example:

```
image = cv2.imread('path_here', 0)
output = image.copy()
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 110,
                       param1=25, param2=5, minRadius=9, maxRadius=10)
detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for (x, y, r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
    cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(output, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('output', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Where is there a semi-circle in that image?

Comment: @Micka. updated images

Comment: Do you have only squares, lines and half circles? If so, maybe it will be easier to detect the squares and the lines, and the remaining shapes will be half circles.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey. I have following ideas

1. a) You can make a fft transform of semicircle
   b) Make and fft transform of image and remove all that is different from semicircle fft.
2. Try to apply Hough Circle Transform
3. With you can load a neural network detector to detect semicircle's

```
cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorFlow
# or
cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch
```

With  PyTorch or TensorFlow you can make a detector for this